# Refresh partialview

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Need help with refreshing partial views in MVC from ajax call.
In my View page.cshtml

```
 <div id="tblOptions">
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.State , new SelectList(), new {id="ddlstate"})
@html.HiddenFor(model => model.optionsId)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.PrintAddress)
```

........

```
</div>
```

On Page load the model is filled properly and all checkboxes are correctly filled. Now onChange  event of dropdownlist , I need to fill the checkboxes with new model values,

I have an ajax call, which returns jsonresult

```
 $(document).on('change', '#ddlstate', function () {
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
            url: '/Home/CallonChange',
            contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
            data: { PersonCode: '@Model.PersonCode', selectedstate: $('#ddlState').val() },
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
                $('tblOptions').html('');
            }
        })
        .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) //success callback
        {
            if (data != null) {
                // not loading    
                $('tblOptions').html(data);                    
            }
            else { //display error message 
            }
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) //error callback
        {
            //display error message
        });
});
});
```

Its returning the new model in JSON result, but the partial view doesn't reload with the new values.

In Controller, I have two action controllers, one called on Load and one called on SelectionChange

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CallOnLoad(string PersonCode, string selectedstate = "") {
ModelA a = new ModelA(PersonCode, selectedstate);
            return PartialView("Home/page", options);
}

[HttpGet]
public JsonResult CallonChange(string PersonCode, string selectedstate= "")
{
ModelA a = new ModelA(PersonCode, selectedstate);  
return Json(options, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I am not able to reload the partial view. What am I doing wrong? I know its pretty silly somewhere but can't figure it out.

Thanks heaps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help ! It works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 issues with your code.

First the jQuery selector is incorrect for the element you want to and the data to, and it needs to be

```
$('#tblOptions').html(data); // not $('tblOptions')
```

Next, you want to update the element with html, so your method needs to return a `PartialViewResult`, not a `JsonResult` so you should be calling the `CallOnLoad()` method, not `CallonChange()`, so you ajax should be

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '@Url.Action("CallOnLoad", "Home")', // not '/Home/CallonChange'
```

note also that the `contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',` is pointless and can be removed

Alternatively, you could return json using the `CallonChange()` method, and just update the values of the existing elements based on your model properties, for example

```
.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) //success callback
{
    $('#optionsId').val(data.optionsId); // updates the hidden input
    $('#PrintAddress').prop('checked', data.PrintAddress); // update the checkbox
    ....
}
```